# I keep getting errors when trying to execute a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to update two tables, and it is defined as follows

```
CREATE procedure ChangeNames 
@oldname nvarchar(100),
@newname nvarchar(100), 
@tablename nvarchar(100)
AS
Begin
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);
Set @sql  = 'UPDATE' +  @tablename + 'SET NAMES =' +  @newname + 'where 
names =' + @oldname + 
'UPDATE ref_names SET NAMES =' + @newname + 'where names =' + @oldname 
Execute sp_executesql @sql
End`
```

I then execute the procedure as follows:

```
USE [database_name]
GO


exec dbo.ChangeNames
@oldname = 'ab', 
@newname = 'cd', 
@tablename = 'ef' 

GO
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are traveling down a path that will lead to lots of frustration and problems. First, as Ezlo noted, you need to learn how to write and debug dynamic sql. And you can't debug what you cannot see. Second, you need to master basic tsql before you attempt dynamic sql. You are using sp_executesql but not in a way that is recommended (see Larnu). And perhaps most importantly, a procedure that makes a very specific change to any table based on a parameter is a poor design choice. That also suggests schema issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few spaces between keywords and single quotes and when delimiting literal values:

```
Set @sql = '
    UPDATE ' +  @tablename + ' SET 
        NAMES = ''' +  @newname + ''' 
    WHERE
        names = ''' + @oldname + ''' 

    UPDATE ref_names SET 
        NAMES = ''' + @newname + '''
    WHERE
        names = ''' + @oldname + ''''
```

It's recommended to use `PRINT` to check the generated SQL before executing dynamic SQL, you will be able to spot these mistakes.

```
PRINT (@sql)
-- Execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Also add `QUOTENAME` to object names, like your dynamic table reference. The object name might have characters that break your dynamic SQL, such as spaces. Using `QUOTENAME` will correctly escape them.

```
Set @sql  = 'UPDATE ' +  QUOTENAME(@tablename) + --...
```

One last thing, make sure the value you are passing to search and update have escaped single quotes as they will also break your dynamic SQL otherwise.

So if you want to update values to `FLIGHT CENTRE's TRAVEL GROUP` (note the single quote in the middle) you will have to actually write `FLIGHT CENTRE''s TRAVEL GROUP` so the quote is escaped correctly.

Comment: Syntax like `''' + @newname + '''` could still be injected into. Rather than trusting the source application to provide a "safe" string, and hope no one that shouldn't get's access to the SP, it's far better to take the pessimistic view and ensure you make the dynamic SQL safe at the time it is executed. Either by appropriately quoting the string or parametrisation.

Comment: @Larnu yes, using parameters would be the best approach here.

Answer (score 2):

I would parametrise your SQL, rather than concatenating the values, and quote the dynamic object name; it makes it far safer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ChangeNames @oldname nvarchar(100),
                             @newname nvarchar(100),
                             @tablename sysname --changed to sysname, as that's the appropriate datatype for an object's name
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'SET names = @New' + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'WHERE names = @old;' + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'UPDATE ref_names' + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'SET names = @New' + NCHAR(10) + 
               N'WHERE names = @old;';
     PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@new nvarchar(100), @old nvarchar(100)', @new = @newname, @old = @oldname;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space after update keyword
`Set @sql  = 'UPDATE ' +  @tablename + 'SET NAMES =' +  @newname + 'where`

Comment: This would leave the OP's SP open to injection; I don't recommend this.